# Creating Anonymous AttributeConverter during context initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a generic jpa `AttributeConverter` that converts a dbValue to the specified `ConvertableDbConstant`:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true) // this would only work on the concrete Converter implementation
public class GenericDbValueToEnumConverter<E extends ConvertableDbConstant<DbValue>, DbValue> implements AttributeConverter<E, DbValue> {


  @Getter
  private Class<E> clazz;

  @Override
  public DbValue convertToDatabaseColumn(E attribute) {
    return attribute.getDbValue(); 
  }

  @Override
  public E convertToEntityAttribute(DbValue dbData) {
    return Arrays.stream(clazz.getEnumConstants())
                 .filter(v -> v.getDbValue().equals(dbData)).findFirst()
                 .orElse(null));
  }
```

Rather than have to create a bunch of empty concrete classes, I was hoping to create the required converters during startup through Springs BeanFactoryPostProcessor;

```
public class DbValueEnumConstantsBeanFactory implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
  
  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    final var scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);

    scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AssignableTypeFilter(ConvertableDbConstant.class));
    scanner.findCandidateComponents("com.org.base.package")
           .forEach(x -> {
             try {
               final var clazz = Class.forName(x.getBeanClassName());
               final var converter = new GenericDbValueToEnumConverter(clazz);
               beanFactory.registerSingleton(GenericDbValueToEnumConverter.getBeanName(clazz.getName()), converter);
               log.info("Registering AttributeConverter for {} with name {}", x.getClass().getSimpleName(), x);

             } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
           });
  }
}
```

While the Converters are being registered into the applicationContext, they're being ignored by (whichever) persistence hooks used to add the AttributeConverter(s) to the persistence provider.  How can I achieve this during the `postProcessBeanFactory` invocation?  All of the examples I've seen would require the concrete classes I am trying to avoid.

By the way, I am using Springboot version '3.1.1', and spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.